# BigQuery automatically deletes created tables through integration

Tags: google-bigquery

Once a day, my CPM integration loads data into a Bigquery table. But starting from May 9, all new tables are automatically deleted.
The method that deletes data - InternalTableExpired.
Table settings set to "Table expiration - NEVER"
Attached screenshot with logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5T9W.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ephz.jpg)

My development team says there are no errors in the integration code.
I also checked all permissions and roles in bigquery